# How to calculate or estimate the area of such implicit region about function $x^{\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

How to estimate or calculate the area enclosed by the implicit equation.

$$x^{\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}}+y^{\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{y}}}=\mathrm{e}$$

It is possible to prove that the area is between $13$ and $15$?

I draw the curve by Asymptote(http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/).

```
import graph;
import contour;
size(200);
real f(real x){return x^(1/(1/x + x));};
real g(real x, real y) {return f(x)+f(y);}
draw(contour(g,(.1,.1),(8,8),new real[]{exp(1)},operator ..),blue+2);
xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your plot has the wrong exponents: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2F%28x%2B1%2Fx%29%29+%2B+y%5E%281%2F%28y%2B1%2Fy%29%29%3De+plot+from+x%3D0+to+10%2C+y%3D0+to+10

Comment: Looks like a predator-prey phase diagram.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably already solved it, but since it might be useful for someone else I write a couple of strategies using *Wolfram Mathematica 13.0*; obviously everyone can use any other spreadsheet.

---

**Monte Carlo method**

The basic idea is to bombard with `10^n` balls the square of area $A_q$ which encloses the region of plane `D` of interest which goes from vertex `(2,2)` to vertex `(7,7)` and to count the `m` balls that also fall internally to `D`. The area of `D` is therefore estimated by $A_q\,m/10^n$. It goes without saying that a good *pseudorandom real number generator* is crucial here:

```
Table[m = 0; Do[{x, y} = RandomReal[{2, 7}, 2];
      If[x^(1/(x + 1/x)) + y^(1/(y + 1/y)) > E, ++m], {10^n}];
      25. m / 10^n, {n, 7}]
```

> {12.5, 12.25, 13.675, 13.77, 13.7047, 13.7454, 13.7577}

or more efficiently:

```
Table[z = RandomReal[{2, 7}, {2, 10^n}];
      25. Total@Boole@Thread[Total[z^(1/(z + 1/z))] > E] / 10^n, {n, 8}]
```

> {15., 15.5, 13.725, 13.87, 13.726, 13.7676, 13.7607, 13.7615}

The calculated area is the better the larger it's `n`.

---

**Discrete Fourier Transform + Gauss-Green theorem**

First, I tabulate *the coordinates of some points of the boundary* proceeding counterclockwise:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^(1/(x + 1/x)) + y^(1/(y + 1/y))

pts = Table[FindRoot[f[ρ Cos[θ] + 4, ρ Sin[θ] + 4] == E,
            {ρ, 1}][[1, 2]] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} + {4, 4},
            {θ, 0, 2 π, π/50}];
```

Through *Discrete Fourier Transform*, I determine a *trigonometric fit of least squares* to the data:

```
TrigFit[v_, m_, {x_, x0_, x1_}] := Module[{fc, fs, i, imax, j, n, t},
  n = Length[v]; imax = Min[m, Floor[(n - 1) / 2]]; t = 2 π (x - x0)/(x1 - x0);
  fc = Table[Sum[v[[j + 1]] Cos[2 π i j / n] / n, {j, 0, n - 1}], {i, 0, imax}];
  fs = Table[Sum[v[[j + 1]] Sin[2 π i j / n] / n, {j, 0, n - 1}], {i, 0, imax}];
  fc[[1]] + 2 Sum[fc[[i + 1]] Cos[i t] + fs[[i + 1]] Sin[i t], {i, 1, imax}]]

{x[t_], y[t_]} = TrigFit[pts, 50, {t, 0, 2 π}];
```

Finally, I *calculate the area enclosed* by this parametric curve using the *Gauss-Green theorem*:

```
NIntegrate[x[t] y'[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

> 13.7592

If you want to check, it's also possible to *superimpose the implicit curve on the parametric one*:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]],
     ContourPlot[f[x, y] == E, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image]

where it's evident that they overlap perfectly, so the calculated area is very close to the exact one!

Comment: Is it possible to get an analytical answer?

Comment: If only pursue numerical solutions, we can use `NIntegrate[Boole[x^(1/(x+1/x))+y^(1/(y+1/y))>=E],{x,0,7},{y,0,7},Method->"LocalAdaptive"]` directly