# What is the area of intersection between two circular sectors? (Where can I find more information?)

Tags: geometry, area

I am trying to find an expression for the area of the intersection of two circular sectors.
There are some obvious and trivial solutions for some special cases,  but I'm trying to generalize.

Here is an example of the kind of problem I'm envisioning:

[image: Two circular sectors, A and B, overlap. Their centres share no xy-coordinates, they subtend different angles and vectors parallel to the anticlockwise-most part of their areas point in different directions.]

I have tried to work out ways of dissecting the shapes and calculating areas with trigonometry or integration.
At the moment, I'm playing with polar coordinates and integrating, treating the centre of A as the origin, then generating expressions for each line of B's perimeter.

I've also been trying to find examples of where this might have been solved before. So far, though, I haven't found anything useful.

- Are there any formulae that I should be looking at?
- Does this kind of problem crop up anywhere else that I could research?
- Even better, does anyone have a good starting point so I can derive it myself?

Comment: You should start by outlining each of the possible cases (one is [well-known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html))

Comment: This doesn't look too hard. The shape is a tetragon with some curved edges. Two of its vertices are intersection points which you haven't marked. Dissect the shape using its four vertices, and you can calculate its area in terms of triangles and [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved (in a somewhat fancy way) by using Green's Theorem. Green's Theorem converts the area calculation to a line integral around the oriented boundary of the region. That boundary consists of circular arcs and line segments, both of which are easy to parametrize. You will need to know all the vertices of the region in your picture.
See this related post. [area between three annulli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586040/how-to-find-the-area-of-intersection-of-three-rings-annulus/4586470#4586470)

Comment: For the larger problem I'm working on, this seems like a great path to follow, thank you!  
I am sure I can find the vertices of the region and equations for each of the curves/lines. This was almost exactly how I had started to continue working the problem since posting, so I'm glad I seem to be on the right road!

Comment: Pun intended I assume?

Answer (score 2):

In short, we want to calculate the double integral:

$$
||D|| \equiv \iint\limits_D 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,,
$$

$$
D \equiv \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \le 1, \; |y|\cos\frac{\alpha}{2} \le x\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}, \; (x-x_C)^2 + (y-y_C)^2 \le r^2, \\ \left|(y-y_C)\cos\gamma-(x-x_C)\sin\gamma\right|\cos\frac{\beta}{2} \le \left((x-x_C)\cos\gamma+(y-y_C)\sin\gamma\right)\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\right\}
$$

with $x_C,y_C \in \mathbb{R}$, $r\ge0$ and $0 \le \alpha,\beta,\gamma \le 2\pi$ known parameters.

For example, assuming the following numerical values:

```
{xC, yC, r, α, β, γ} = {1, -1, 6/5, π/3, π/4, 4π/7};

domainA = x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && Abs[y] Cos[α/2] <= x Sin[α/2];

domainB = (x - xC)^2 + (y - yC)^2 <= r^2 && Abs[(y - yC) Cos[γ] - (x - xC) 
          Sin[γ]] Cos[β/2] <= ((x - xC) Cos[γ] + (y - yC) Sin[γ]) Sin[β/2];

RegionPlot[{domainA, domainB}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
           Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> False,
           GridLines -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[domainA && domainB, {x, y}], 
           WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

> 0.308723

which can be obtained in an elementary way by applying the [Monte Carlo method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4571234/247735):

```
ParallelTable[m = 0; Do[{x, y} = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2];
              If[domainA && domainB, ++m], {10^n}];
              16. m/10^n, {n, 8}]
```

> {0., 0.64, 0.416, 0.28, 0.29792, 0.308816, 0.306883, 0.308919}

As has already been written, for the exact calculation an efficient way is the application of the *Gauss-Green theorem* in the plane, but the difficult part is to decline the various cases and sub-cases involving the six parameters!